# Angular $http.POST sending empty body sometimes

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, angularjs-directive, angular-http

I am using $http to post some data, and receiving it on GAE backend with python. Most of the time everything is working fine, but some times the post body is empty. This keeps happening for specific users, which makes me wonder if it's something hardware / os related.

Angular Code:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/some_url',
            data: {
                data_1: $rootScope.me,
                data_2: some_other_data
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            // Do something here
        }).error(function(data) {
            // Do something here
        });
```

For more context: We are using WkWebView to display the site in our iOS app.

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools to see what it thinks is being sent.

Comment: This is happening in production. Unfortunately we aren't able to reproduce it to debug. Tried logging in as the effected user but it works perfectly for us.

Comment: I have a hard time believing the above code is doing that. Either there is another call in your Javascript, or you have a fronting server (apache, nginx) changing the request.

Comment: I am using webapp2 (python + GAE). And tried to log the request as `logging.info(self.request.body)`. Also this works for most users except few who are like permanently blocked. And since we logging in that user isn't causing the issue, I highly doubt anything is happening on server side to cause this. Am asking if this could possibly have some issue if some variable is undefined or some H/W issue ?